# bootstrap's collapse doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu

i have written this code using bootstrap to use the collapse-menu.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Up and Running with Bootstrap</title>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 shim for IE backwards compatibility -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Roux Academy Conference</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">The Artists</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">The Art</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Venue</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this code has to collapse the list items on resizing the browser window but it doesnt work in any of the browser(FF, Chrome or IE).

thanx in advance.

Comment: Does `bootstrap.js` contain the collapse/transition Bootstrap JavaScript?  I know using the site you can choose which modules you want.. maybe you don't have all the JS you need loaded?

Comment: What kind of effect did you want? Like this?- [http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/Dnday](http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/Dnday) This uses http://www.bootstrapcdn.com

Comment: yes it contains the collapse/transition Bootstrap javascript

Comment: Or with some code from [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs), your code changed slightly makes: http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/gFLfz which is responsive.

Comment: You do not appear to be using the code for the collapse menu. It should look like this: http://www.bootply.com/65023

Comment: the effect that i wanted must hav a button that contains all the navbar options on resizing the window.
it is similar to the effect on bootstrap's homepage [link](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) when u resize the window check the navbar.@harley

Comment: @PrathamMehta my second example, (as well as skelly's) does just that.

Comment: but when i click that button nothing happens in my browser

Comment: @PrathamMehta Shall I add it as a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right HTML wasn't being used to make the nav bar responsive.

I used the code from http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs , and made:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-inner">
  <div class="container">
     <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="brand" href="#">Roux Academy Conference</a>
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">The Artists</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Art</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Venue</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

This makes the desired behaviour as long as the the necessary JS/CSS is linked.

Working code here: http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/gFLfz (FF,Chrome Only?)

or here: http://www.bootply.com/65033 (IE also)

Comment: but the button is just visible nothing happens when i click on it in my browser.
it works fine in the link u provided.

Comment: or i guess there's some problem with js in my browsers..it is enabled in all the browsers but it works only for the websites and not the code.

Comment: what can i do to solve the error related to javascript in my computer because its been bugging me since few days..even a simple code to display an alert box doesn't work

Comment: @PrathamMehta I think that it is OK now- see the bootply.com link.

Comment: @PrathamMehta If it was helpful, please tick my answer as it solved yr issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is some mistake in your html ..

add this for collapse menu:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
```

add this for collapse menu button

```
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar">
            </span>
        </button>
```

Please Try this:

```
<head >
    <title></title>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 shim for IE backwards compatibility -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar">
                </span>
            </button>
            <a class="brand" href="#">Roux Academy Conference</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#">The Artists</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">The Art</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Venue</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```